# How to load different configurations in the same file using different Configurations (ConfigurationInterface) in Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony-components, symfony-config-component

I'm using the following Symfony components:

```
"require": {
    "symfony/dependency-injection": "~3.0",
    "symfony/yaml": "~3.0",
    "symfony/config": "~3.0",
    "symfony/console": "~3.0",
    "symfony/validator": "~3.0",
    "symfony/event-dispatcher": "~3.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "gedex/janrain-api": "~0.1",
    "monolog/monolog": "~1.0"
},
```

I have a `forms.yaml` and `services.yaml`. Services config file has information about services to be loaded by `DependencyInjection` component. But Forms config file has custom definition for my `Forms`service (which uses a custom Configuration class.

I would like to know if I can merge `services` and `forms` into a single `config.yaml` and still have the `DependencyInjection` and `Forms` get their configuration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything defined in `config.yaml` apart from `parameters`, needs to be used by an `Extension`.

The `Extension` receives the config part that belongs to it (defined by the `getAlias` method).

The extension then can call a `Configurator` which will process a "well known" configuration, and you can add defaults, etc. This will return a config array.

You can then set a parameter in the container, having this configuration array. The container that the Extension receives is an empty one that then gets merged with the real one, receiving the parameters.

Then you can add a `CompilerPass` and use these parameters to bind them to your service.